# pick_event to get a point using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use a `pick_event` to directly access the exact values of a point by a mouse click:

```
def plot(self, x_values: list, y_values: list):
    def pick_handler(event):
        x, y = event.mouseevent.xdata, event.mouseevent.ydata
        print(x, y)

    ...
    self.sc, = self.axis.plot(x_values, y_values, 'bo', markersize=7, picker=7)
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', pick_handler)
    ...
```

The problem is that I don't get the EXACT values as the `picker` is set to 7. 
Is there a way of getting those values without compute the nearest point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you don't want to know the position of the mouse (`event.mouseevent.xdata`) but the index of the event (`event.ind`) to select the correct values from the artist (`event.artist`) that is picked.

What you are asking for is part of [this example in the matplotlib event guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#simple-picking-example).

I can only quote it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')

line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    print('onpick points:', points)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: that's right! thank you, although I had to use `ind = event.ind[0]` instead of `ind = event.ind`

Comment: No longer relevant.
AttributeError: 'PickEvent' object has no attribute 'ind'