# Follow up question to: pick_event to get a point using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm really new to python.
I have a follow-up question to this one ([pick_event to get a point using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034489/pick-event-to-get-a-point-using-matplotlib)):

I have some data points and I want to pick a certain one with a function and then play around with it later using the variable workspace.

So I would like to save, not only print the variable. How can I do this? I tried several different ways (pickle works almost right), but unfortunately its always one step behind. So when I actually run the script, it takes the data from my last pick, instead of the actual pick. I assume this has got something to do with the time when

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

is executed. But I really don't know how to deal with it. Very thankful for any help!

My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    example_dict = {points}
    pickle_out = open("point.pickle","wb")
    pickle.dump(example_dict, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()
    print('onpick points:', points)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')
line = ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
plt.show()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

pickle_in = open("point.pickle","rb")
point = pickle.load(pickle_in)
print('After picking:')
print(point)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code takes the data from your last pick, since the first thing you do when you run the script is not picking data (which then gets pickled), but you are reading in your pickled data from the last time you ran the script. This is also why you get an error the very first time you run your script (or rename your pickle file), since it tries to read in a pickled data file that does not yet exist.

By *connecting* the `onpick` function in the line

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

you are not yet *calling* it. You are only calling it when you pick, by which point the code part afterwards which is reading your pickled data has already been executed. To actually get what is pickled *after* you pick you would have to call this code

```
point = pickle.load(open("point.pickle","rb"))
print('After picking:')
print(point)
```

either inside the `onpick` function or in another function that you trigger only after you actually pick a point (e.g. connect a `'key_press_event'` that will print out your pickled data).

**EDIT**

For example your code could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
    example_dict = {points}
    pickle_out = open("point.pickle","wb")
    pickle.dump(example_dict, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()
    print('onpick points:', points)
    postProcess()

def postProcess():
    pickle_in = open("point.pickle","rb")
    point = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    print('After picking:')
    print(point)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')
line = ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), 'o', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
plt.show()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

<s>Now, when you pick a point with a mouse click and then press 'p' to show what is stored in your pickled file you can see that you are actually storing your data correctly, you just weren't *reading* it at the correct moment.</s>

**EDIT 2:**
Edited the code so you don't have to press a key to process your data.

Comment: Thank you @FreyaW ! This makes things a bit clearer. But I still didn't manage to actually store the point variable. You mentioned the `key_press_event`, but I didn't figure out how to use it in this case to somehow stop the future code being executed. An example would be great! Thank you!

Comment: @Dylan, I added a code example where reading in and printing the pickled file is moved to a function connected to a keypressevent. Now your `pickle.load` code part isn't executed as soon as you run the script, but only after you press a button. Now you can see that even in your first code you DID actually store the point variable, you just weren't checking its content at the right time.

Comment: Thank you @FreyaW. But still, after

`fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onkey)`

i can’t access my new point information in the script. And that’s exactly what I would want. I tried adding a  new function to read in and then return the new value, but it still reads in the old file:

`def myfunc():
    pickle_in = open("point.pickle","rb")
    point = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    return point

point = myfunc()
print('at the end:')
print(point)`

So how do I get this new point information into my workspace to continue the script?

Comment: @Dylan, you have yourself a logic/time problem here. you want to access your information on what point you WILL click as soon as you execute the script? That is not possible. So, could you describe exactly what kind of behaviour you are looking for? Because as soon as you execute the script EVERYTHING you wrote will be exectued IMMEDIATELY, unless it is a function that is coupled to an action (pick/key). So you IMMEDIATELY ask your script: hey, what point was picked? BEFORE you pick a point! That's not possible. You could divide your code into two scripts, one to pick, one to print your info.

Comment: Thank you @FreyaW! But yes, I would like to run the script until I pick and then let the script use my picked data for further processing. I found the `plt.ginput(n=click)` function which solves my problem. But I'm still curious if this is really not possibe with a seperate function.

Comment: @Dylan you can let your function `onpick(event)` call a seperate function at the end that then does your processing. plt.ginput() will wait and pause your script until you clicked `n` times, but doesn't work for a second click.

Comment: @Dylan I edited the code so you don't have to press a key to print your data, the function `postProcess` is called automatically. There really is no reason to do the post processing in the main body of the script instead of in a function that gets called after you click.